# xpath: How to combine multiple conditions on different axes

Tags: xpath, multiple-conditions, multiple-axes

I try to extract all links based on these three conditions:

- Must be part of `<div data-test="cond1">`
- Must have a `<a href="..." class="cond2">`
- Must not have a `<img src="..." class="cond3">`

The result should be "/product/1234".

```
<div data-test="test1">
  <div>
    <div data-test="cond1">
      <a href="/product/1234" class="cond2">Link 1</a>
      <div class="test4">
        <div class="test5">
          <div class="test6">
            <div class="test7">
              <div class="test8">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-test="test2">
  <div>
    <div data-test="cond1">
      <a href="/product/5678" class="cond2">Link 2</a>
      <div class="test4">
        <div class="test5">
          <div class="test6">
            <div class="test7">
              <div class="test8">
                <img src="bild.jpg" class="cond3">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm able to extract the links with the following xpath query.

```
//div[starts-with(@data-test,"cond")]/a[starts-with(@class,"cond")]/@href
```

(I know the first part is not really neccessary. But better safe than sorry.)

But I'm still struggling with excluding the links containing an descendant img tag and how to add it to the query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```bash
//div[@data-test="cond1" and not(.//img[@class="cond3"])]
/a[@class="cond2"]
/@href
```

```
/product/1234
```